# Passing data from List Item to child component react native

Tags: react-native, state, react-native-flatlist, react-props

I have Flatlist display data in a ListItem from a fetch request as shown.

**ListTrips.js**

```
export default class ListTrip extends Component {
....
  toggleModalConfirmTrip = item => {
if (this.ModalConfirmTrip) {
  this.ModalConfirmTrip.toggleModal();
}
};

<FlatList
   data={data}
   renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <ListItem
         *onPress={() => this.toggleModalConfirmTrip(item)*}
         roundAvatar
         title={`${item.location_from} to ${item.location_to} `}
         subtitle={item.user[0].name}
         rightTitle={item.timeStamp}
         avatar={
            <Image
               source={require('../assests/carLogo.png')}
               style={{ width: 40, height: 50, borderRadius: 10 }}
            />
         }
         containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0, paddingBottom: 10 }}
      />
   )}
   // Uses object ID to iterate over the trips
   keyExtractor={item => item._id}
   ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
   ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
   ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
   refreshing={refreshing}
   onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
           .
           . 
           .
```

I want to pass the data of the selected item to a modal component (a child of ListTrips) so I can display it.  I attempted to do it by passing `item` in  `onPress={() => this.toggleModalConfirmTrip(item)}` but it didn't work.
I know I have to pass it as a prop down to my child component but I'm sure how.

ModalConfirmTrip.js

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. What didn't work? What was the error you got? Please also show the code for the `ListItem` component.

Comment: I'm simply displaying console.log(state,props) to check is the data passed through onPress of an item.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `ListItem` must be having access to `item` as a prop, the `ListItem` being the stateless React component there. So you should call the `onPress` of your touchable inside the `ListItem` with the `item` parameter.

```
const ListItem = ({item, onPress, otherProps}) => {
    return (
        ...
     <Button onPress={() => onPress(item)} />
        ...
    );
}
```

Then your ListItem should be called/rendered as follows:

```
<ListItem
   onPress={(item) => this.toggleModalConfirmTrip(item)}
   roundAvatar
   ... />
```

I hope this helps. If you have any third party UI library for the `ListItem` then please specify that.

Comment: My ListItem is being displayed in the return of my ListTrips Component.
I'm not sure what you mean by introducing a button, I am toggling the ModalConfirmTrip modal with onPress.  I edited some of my code above,

I'm not using an external UI Library, thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of your `ListItem` component ? 
I introduced the button because it looks like your `ListItem` component exposed an onPress prop, so internally in the definition there must be some touchable widget like `TouchableOpacity` or `Button` or `TouchableNativeFeedback`.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry my ListItem comes from react-native-elements so I'm using the predisposed props there.